# command line arguments in python with aws lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Python script for generating fake logs. The execution requires that I pass certain parameters as command line arguments. I want to understand how can I pass these command line parameters in AWS lambda function.

For example,

here's the command line argument to run the script locally:

`python fake-log-gen.py -n 1000000 -o LOG -s 1`

how do I pass these arguments when the function is deployed through AWS lambda

Comment: You should rather have a look at the program and see if you can `import` its main function, and call it directly. Any halfway decent script should be written such that the CLI invocation is merely a wrapper around this way of calling it. If the script is exclusively callable via CLI arguments, you’ll need some ugly hacks…

Comment: What do you mean by "when the function is deployed through AWS lambda"? Have you converted the script into an actual AWS Lambda function, or are you wanting to call out from the Lambda function and run the script from an Operating System shell?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want to run that python script through AWS lambda. Right now it's running locally on my laptop. Further I want to know if there is a way to pass command line arguments for functions running in AWS lambda

Answer (score 2):

When [`invoke()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) is called on an AWS Lambda function, a `payload` can be provided. This payload will be provided to the Lambda object via the `event parameter`.

If the Lambda function is invoked by an AWS service, then that service is responsible for providing the `event`. For example, when an AWS Lambda function is triggered by an object being created in an Amazon S3 bucket, then the S3 service will provide an `event` to details which bucket and object triggered the Lambda function.

If you are directly triggering the Lambda function via `invoke()`, then you can provide the `event` data to be sent to the function.

As for invoking the `fake-log-gen.py` script, it would be best if you converted the script into a Lambda function that directly executes the code. This is preferable to having the Lambda function 'call out' to the operating system to run a Python script.